# rss feed xml: cannot access images after converting rss feed to xml object

Tags: php, xml, image, rss, feed

In the http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286, there are many images. However, when i convert it into and xml object with simplXmlElement, i'm not able to see the images.My code:

```
if (function_exists("curl_init")){
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//print_r($data);   //here i'm able to see the images
     $doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data);
     print_r($doc);   //here i'm not able to see the images
  }
```

Can someone tell me on how can I access the images after converting to xml object? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate trough the `<content:encoded>` tags of the individual `<items>` in the `<channel>` main tag. I would use the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to select the tags. Once you get the element you want you can grep the `<img>` out of them with string manipulation tools like [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

***Edit:*** added more refined image tag matching, that excludes ads from feedburner and other cdns.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286"));

foreach ($xml->xpath('//item/content:encoded') as $desc) {
    preg_match_all('!(?<imgs><img.+?src=[\'"].*?http://feeds.feedburner.com.+?[\'"].+?>)!m', $desc, $>

    foreach ($m['imgs'] as $img) {
        print $img;
    }
}
```

The `<content:encoded>` tag is namespaced, so if you want to use simplexml's built in property mapping, you have to deal with it like this:

```
// obtain simplexml object of the feed as before
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $namespaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
    $content = $item->children($namespaces['content']);
    print $content->encoded; // use it howevery you want
}
```

You can read more from the xpath query language [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

Comment: why ru using file_get_contents? can I just use $xml=simplexml_load_string($data)? YOur http addr is not the same as mine? is it a typo? mine is http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286.

Comment: Just to make the snippet shorter, doesn't matter how you obtain the feed, you could also use `simplexml_load_file('http://.../')`, too.

Comment: Oh, the '?l' was a typo, however doesn't matter of in the result. The original feedburner url gives you different result for your browser then when you call it with curl/php. To get to the xml feed with the browser follow this url: http://feeds.feedburner.com/rb286?format=xml .

Comment: is it better not to use curl? now i tried using simpleXml_load_file("http//feeds.feedburner.com/rb286?format=xml"). I still don't see any <content:encoded> tag. Why i'm not able to see that tag? However, the images are displaying. Please help....i'm new to xml, xpath, rss feed. Thank you.

Comment: Curl is fine too, don't need to change it. I'm not sure what you mean "seeing" the tags, but simply printing out `SimpleXmlElement` instances probably not what you want. The sample code should work (at least in my testing enviroment it did).

Comment: Yes, i am talking abt printing out the instances of SimpleXmlElement (print_r($doc)). When i do that, i'm able to see the item's link, title and description tags. In the same manner, i should be able to see that <content:encoded> tag too right?

Comment: Well, not by default because of namespacing, i've updated the example.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I will try that out and let you know. :) I got to read up on namespaces. I have no idea on what is that.

Comment: i've decided on using ur first solution:foreach ($xml->xpath('//item/content:encoded') as $desc) { 
    preg_match_all('/(?<imgs><img[^>]+>)/m', $desc, $m); 
    foreach ($m['imgs'] as $img) { 
        print $img; 
    } 
} 
but print $img is not only giving the image but also some extra text such as:email this, technocrati links, add a comment, save to delicious, add to delicious, digg this. How can I get rid of those texts? please help, i've been trying to make this work for a whole day.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14340/discussion-between-complex857-and-vaanipala)